# Orientdb reads out wrong time

Tags: java, orientdb

I am using Orientdb with Eclipse and the orientdb-client jar. I use the following statement to read out Messages:

```
List<ODocument> result = connection.command(
                new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(
                        "SELECT * FROM Message"))
                .execute();
```

At first glance the results looks right, but then i realized that the time i read out from a DATTIME field is wrong.
When i run the  query "select * from Message ", the locahost version gives me the following results (just a part of it): 
[image]
When i run the java snippet from above, the results looks like : 
[image]

For the formating i use a SimpleDateFormat:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
String time = formatter.format(each.field("Time"));
```

So why is the hour of the date different ( 2 hours) ? Could it be a Timezone issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because database returns results in database's timezone.
You can see it from studio in section Db->configuration.
Command to update timezone looks like
`alter database timezone GMT+6`

Comment: For me the solution was GMT+2. Thanks!